# How to get the real value of variable declared outside the loop, after using that varible in loop

Tags: c++, loops, variables

I was working with loops and stuck with this problem.

I had ***declared a variable outside the main code*** and then **used it in the loop**, but when I am returning the value of that variable after that loop, ***I am unable to get that value again***.

```
int n;

int main () {

    // Sum of N natural numbers using FOR LOOP

    // 1st METHOD

    cin>>n;

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
        sum=sum+i;
    }

    cout<<"\nThe sum of first "<<n<<" natural number is : "<<sum<<endl;


    // 2nd METHOD

    int sum4=0;
    for( n ; n>0 ; n--){
        sum4+=n;
    }

    cout<<"\nThe sum of first "<< :: n<<"  natural number is : "<<sum4<<endl;


    // Sum of N natural numbers using WHILE LOOP

    int sum1=0;
    while(n>0){
        sum1+=n;
        n--;
    }

    cout<<"\nThe sum of first "<<n<<" natural number is : "<<sum1<<endl;


    // Sum of N natural numbers using DO WHILE LOOP

    int sum2=0;
    do{
        sum2+=n;
        n--;
    } while(n>0);

    cout<<"\nThe sum of first "<<n<<" natural number is : "<<sum2<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The sum of first 55 natural number is : 1540
The sum of first **0**  natural number is : 1540
The sum of first **0 **natural number is : **0**
The sum of first **-1** natural number is : **0**
```

Can I declare a universal variable and use it in a loop, and at the same time after the loop quits it does not change the value of that variable and give the output as declared?

Comment: The second method modifies `n`, so it isn't what the user input for the output, or the later methods

Comment: In your second method, you change the value of n. If you change the value of a variable, it will be changed. What you can do is create another variable and initialize it to the value of the original, so you can change the new variable and leave the original one untouched.

Comment: Change the second loop from `for( n ; n>0 ; n--) sum4+=n;` to `for( int i = n ; i>0 ; i--) sum4+=i;`. Similarly for the later loops; work on a **copy** of `n`, not on `n` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I declare a universal variable and use it in a loop and at the same time after loop quits it does not change the value of that variable and gives the output as declared.

Let me rephrase that as: "Can I modify something, and at the same time, ensure it is not modified?"

No, you can't. What you can do is *copy* something, and modify the copy.

```
for(int i=n; i>0 ; i--){
    sum4+=i;
}

int sum1=0;
int i = n;
while(i>0){
    sum1+=i;
    i--;
}

int sum2=0;
i = n;
do{
    sum2+=i;
    i--;
} while(i>0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the original variable to a separate variable declared outside the loop, and then just print that other variable at the end of the code. It would be unchanged.

Comment: This seems more like a comments than an actual answer. Until you have enough reputation to actually post comments, please be patient. Posting comments as answers will only get them down-voted, making you loose reputation.